# Keyboard input language switched spontaneously

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

How do I turn off the possibility to switch keyboard language?

It seems like I never get rid of this

[image]

(screenshot from a vertical taskbar)

My goal is to run english windows with swedish keyboard.

I am able to hide the language bar for a while and then it reappears. Sometimes the language is switched without notice.

There are no hotkeys defined for input languages:

[image]